# Cannot run tests via sbt in Scala

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying out a simple HelloWorld example. Here is my directory structure:

```
hello
  build.sbt
  main
    scala
      Hello.scala
  test
    scala
      HelloTest.scala
```

`Hello.scala` contains a `sayHello` function that I am trying to call from a simple test in `HelloTest.scala`. Here is my build.sbt:

```
name := "Hello"

organization := "tycon"

scalaVersion := "2.11.2"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.1" % "test"
```

And here is an sbt run that does not run any tests:

```
$ sbt
[info] Set current project to scala (in build
file:~/git/scala/hello/main/scala/)
> compile
[info] Updating
{file:~/git/scala/hello/main/scala/}scala...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to
~/git/scala/hello/main/scala/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[success] Total time: 3 s, completed Sep 17, 2014 9:04:00 AM
> test
[info] Passed: Total 0, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 0
[info] No tests to run for test:test
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Sep 17, 2014 9:04:03 AM
```

I tried suggestions from other answers: replaced `%%` with `%` and substituted `scalatest_2.10` for `scalatest` in `libraryDependencies`, and changed scalaVersion to `2.10.0`. None of them worked. And yes, I was `reload`ing each time `build.sbt` changed.

I believe that I am missing something very basic. I would appreciate any help. I am new to Scala.

Edit: For the sake of completeness, here are the two scala files:

Hello.scala:

```
trait Hello {
  def sayHello () = {
    println ("Hello, World!")
  }
}
```

HelloTest:scala:

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite

class HelloTest extends FunSuite with Hello {
  test("say hello") {
    sayHello()
  }
}
```

Edit2: I changed the directory structure as suggested by ajozwik and Gabriele, but sbt still doesn't run the test:

```
~/git/scala/hello/src/main/scala$ sbt
[info] Set current project to scala (in build
file:~/git/scala/hello/src/main/scala/)
> test
[info] Passed: Total 0, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 0
[info] No tests to run for test:test
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Sep 17, 2014 9:36:24 AM
```

Comment: `src/main/scala` `src/test/scala` ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The directory structure should be

```
hello
  build.sbt
  src
    main
      scala
        Hello.scala
    test
      scala
        HelloTest.scala
```

i.e. you're missing the outer `src` directory.

Also, you need to run `sbt` from the root of your project, and not from within a subfolder.

Comment: @GowthamKaki did u recompile?

Comment: @GowthamKaki see my edit. You have to run sbt from the root folder.

Comment: Thanks, Gabriele. Running from root folder helped. Since sbt enforces directory structure, I assumed that it knows the location of the build file. Apparently not.